# Firebase auth web with apple login

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I'm stuck on configuring Apple Login for my web app using Firebase Auth.

I did all the configuration on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/apple but cant seem to find the apple-developer-domain-association.txt file to download and host on firebase hosting.

Firebase configuration:

Services Id:
- The bundle id on the identifier page

Apple Team Id:
- Full App name

Key Code:
- The key identifier

Secret Key
- Content of key file downloaded from the developers page

With this config I get the invalid_uri on the popup when opened.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ruaridh's answer, make sure that the "domain" is formatted with OUT the leading "https://"

so just: `YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com`

This may seem obvious to some, but I did not see anything in any documentation that specified the format the domain needed to be in. Even Firebase and Apple support were not able to identify improper formatting as an issue in my case. I came across this solution by accident and still cannot find any official documentation of formatting.

I had been stuck on that for a while, so even if it doesn't solve your issue, hopefully it is valuable to others.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to host the `apple-developer-domain-association.txt` on Firebase anymore - I have just implemented Sign in with Apple on a Firebase web app and it wasn't required. Apparently as long as TLS 1.2 is supported (which Firebase handles for you), it should work. Firebase docs seem to be out of date. When configuring your Service ID, it says:

> Your website must support TLS 1.2 or higher.

You should just need to register `https://YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler` in the "Return URLs" when configuring the Service ID in the Apple Developer Console.

Note that Apple doesn't let you use localhost as the return uri, so I found that I couldn't test it locally either.